# How to create MVC files in extjs

Tags: model-view-controller, extjs4

I want to implement gridview given in link http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/example/writer/writer.html....but i want to break this single writer.js file into separate model,view,controller and store file in order to implement exact gridview in MVC architecture format.i.e. i want to create four different files formodel,view,controller and store  for implementing same example. So can you please tell me how will be these four separate files.How to divide this single writer.js files code into model,view,controller and store files.
I am very new to extjs. Please help me.....

Comment: please can someone help me to split this writer.js gridview demo into MVC architecture.

Comment: link you have specified appears to be broken!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i finished Writer function using MVC structure successfully. If u need any help let me know. on form submit, added this code to insert values inside grid row.

```
 form.submit({
 waitMsg: 'Uploading Document...',
 url: 'save-form.php',
 success: function () {
 var values = form.getValues();
 Ext.getCmp('Docdetails').store.insert(0,values);
 form.reset();
 },
 failure: function () {
 Ext.MessageBox.alert ('Message','Saving data failed');
 }
 });
```

Comment: Could you please explain what's MVC about a form's callback-function??